# Unlocking my windows 8.1 phone

Tags: 8.1, lumia-520, unlocking

I have been using a Nokia Lumia 520 since February 2014. I am not into gadgets and all so this phone is perfect for me but I have not unlocked it yet as the unlock code is very expensive. Can you suggest me any other ways which would allow me to use my simcard in it? I am from Nepal.

Comment: Do you mean carrier unlock? You'll need your provider to give you that code.